# How to import dependencies in Git

Tags: git, amazon-rds, s3cmd

I have a project and I want to push it on Git. But locally, my project has some dependencies to RDSCLI (Amazon RDS Command Line Toolkit) and s3cmd. So how do I make sure that if anyone wants to use my project do not have to bother about downloading this software and he can directly run my project without any hassle? Is there a way to achieve this or I need to mention this in the requirements?

Comment: You can't, or at least shouldn't even if you can find a way. That isn't what Git is for. It's for verson-controlling *your own source code*, not distributing binary software or for managing dependencies. Include a README that lists the dependencies of your project, and tell people where they can download RDSCLI.

Comment: @meagar: but my manager has asked me to do so so that my other teammates don't have to install these requirements.

Comment: Very well, but Git as a tool still doesn't support that type of dependency management.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) for dependencies that are maintained by your company (other sources that are required by your top-level project).

Don't use Git *submodules* to store binary files.

But you can use *submodules* to reference an external repository to, let's say, an Open Source project that is needed in your top-level project, for example.

Anyway, most of the git clients today handle the `--recursive` clone automatically, so every checkout should come with dependencies almost transparently.